# curl error TCP connection reset by peer when download DataStax Studio 2.0

Tags: linux, putty, download, connection, curl

I am trying to download DataStax Studio 2.0 on a server. I am using the curl command as follows:

curl -L \
https://downloads.datastax.com/datastax-studio/datastax-studio-2.0.tar.gz

What happens is at the very end, I get a '**curl: (56) TCP connection reset by peer**' error, which seems to be causing not everything to be downloaded properly. With the -v flag added, I get the following additional information:

**SSL read: errno -5961 (PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR)**

I don't think it is an issue with the proxy/port/firewall, since when I tried installing version 6.0 with the same command, it worked just fine. Any ideas to rectify this?

Comment: Which version of curl are you using?

Comment: I believe 7.29. Would it make a difference considered version 6.0 worked fine? Would I have to downgrade?

Comment: So I tried it on a different computer (with curl 7.58) and it worked. Is that likely the reason? Because why would an older version of curl work for version 6 but not version 2?

Comment: The connection errors might be related to network problems. Maybe the other computer had better network connection. I doubt that the version numbers matter.

Comment: The connection that wasn't working only didn't work for version 2, it worked for version 6 though. The network connectivity was very good.